# How to track Blogger and Sites subdomains in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, blogger, google-workspace, google-sites

I am using Google Apps in my domain. In this domain I have a Blogger blog and a Google Sites website. I have setup Google Analytics to track my website and it works fine. I also track blog visits and I see it in Stats page. I want all to be integrated in Google Analytics. I found an option to track subdomains in Analytics but still it needs a Website URL in the settings. I do not understand. I have multiple site URLs:

1. `http://blog.mydomain.com` Blog URL
2. `http://www.mydomain.com` Website URL

How can I do this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your google analytics settings you need to add a new profile for a new domain. Then you need to add the tracking code in the header of the blogger template (blogger->design->edit html, find the `</head>` tag and throw the tracking code right before that closing tag.
after that you just need to verify that it's there and you're done (just did that myself to see if it works and it does).

Comment: It worked indeed but I have to say that the reason for confusion was the new Analytics interface. In the new interface the Default URL is in the Web Property and when you change it, it changes all profiles. In the old interface, each profile has it's own Default URL.